# Best practice to be DRY in terms of style in React Native with components such as TextInput?

Tags: react-native, styles, components

I am using **TextInput** in multiple scenes to render "form" elements. They all share the same style, so what is good practice in React Native in terms of styling? I mean, I could define a style for the TextInput in every single component scene, but is there a way to be more **DRY**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `TextInput` in your own component. Add styles to it, and define props that you use a lot with that component. You can also pass other props (not explicitly defined) for example by using `const { label, value, placeholder, onChange, multiline, onSubmit, ...passProps } = this.props;` and then `<TextInput label={label} ... {...passProps} />`.